# How to use {{a variable [inside] a variable}}?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I’m new to Jekyll and Liquid and there is a little thing I’m trying to do and I can’t figure out how to make it work.

Basically:

```
this.works[well]
```

(I think)

But:

```
this.does.[not].work
this.does[not]work
[this].does.not.work
[this]does.not.work
```

So that is my question: how to insert an individual variable inside a “variable path”?

Basically I’d like to call text strings from different languages, that are in my _data folder for now.
What I would like to do is something akin to:

**_data/en.yml:**

```
hello: ‘Hello!’
```

**page frontmatter:**

```
lang: en
```

**where the string has to appear:**

```
{{ site.data[page.lang]hello }}
```

Any proper way to do this?

Knowing that I will have dozens of strings like this, so it should be as compact as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, it is:

```
site.data[page.lang].hello
```

I have a follow-up issue, it is that I also pass these strings in includes.

This doesn’t work, and gives a syntax error:

```
{% include box.html text=site.data[page.lang].hello %}
```

So I have to do things like this:

```
{% assign hello=site.data[page.lang].hello %}
{% include box.html text=hello %}
```

Which is extremely long and silly: I end up by writing 3 times (!) my variable name, and create a lot of duplicated variables.

Any one knows how to write without writing my string name 3 times?
Thanks!!

(Even more silly because you can use variables with [] in the first part of include, but not in the second one?

```
{% include site.data[page.lang].box text=hello %}
```

would work for instance…)

Answer (score 0):

To insert an individual variable inside a variable path, you need to use square brackets and a dot, like this:

site.data[page.lang].hello

This will access the value of the hello key in the site.data hash, using the value of page.lang as the key

To pass these strings in includes, you can use the raw tag to prevent Liquid from interpreting the curly braces. For example:

{% raw %} {% include box.html text=site.data[page.lang].hello %} {% endraw %}

This will output the literal text inside the raw tag, without trying to parse it as Liquid code